# Is there any Architecture Difference on Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for Access and Excel? Does IIS has anything to do with how it is registered?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access-2010, excel-2010, oledbconnection

I'm currently hitting the wall here. I don't even know where to look or what to look anymore.
I'm working on an application that does some office automation for Access and Excel.

Following are the problems and post problems after each attempt to solve an issee.
1st Solution works for both Access and Excel when runing from Visual Studio. It just doesn’t work when it is published to IIS.

Is there any difference in Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 Provide to for Access and Excel? Or there is another big question behind this?

Current Architecture: 
Machine – x64 Windows 2k8 r2 
Web Application –x64 
IIS 7.0
AccessDatabaseEngine –x64
**Edit -Microsoft Office 2010 x86**
AppPool: .Net 4.0/Integrated/Enable 32-Bit =>False/Identity => Admin(user)

Error:

Uploading of Access Database not working - Microsoft.Oledb.ACE.12.0 connection freezes
Upload of Excel not working - Microsoft.Oledb.ACE.12.0 connection freezes

1st Solution Attempted:
Application built with ‘Any CPU’
Uninstall AccessDatabaseEngine –x64
Repair Microsoft Office 2010 x64

Post Deployment:
Upload of Access Database works

Error:
Upload of Excel not doesn’t work - Microsoft.Oledb.ACE.12.0 provider not registered on the local machine

2st Solution Attempted:
Application built with ‘x86’
Repair Microsoft Office 2010 x64
AppPool- Enable 32-bit => True

Post Deployment:
While hitting the URL – JIT Debugger pops with - Unhandled exception at 0x108d8d10 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.

3nd Solution Attempted:
Install both x86 and x64 AccessDatabaseEngine

Post Deployment:
Upload of Access Database doesn’t work -- 
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {73A4C9C1-D68D-11D0-98BF-00A0C90DC8D9} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Upload of Excel works

**4th Solution:
Post a question on here and wait for reply. 
Please, someone enlight me here, just a hint to keep me out of this dark.**

The code to read access/excel are as following:
Excel:

```
 string csvCONSTRSTRING = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=<FILENAME>;Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;\";";
        using (OleDbConnection objConnection = new OleDbConnection(CONSTRSTRING.Replace("<FILENAME>", fullFileName)))
        {
            DataSet dsImport = new DataSet();
            objConnection.Open();
            DataTable dtSchema = objConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
            if ((null == dtSchema) || (dtSchema.Rows.Count <= 0))
            {
                throw new Exception("Excel doesn't contain any readable table/tab");
            }
            new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]", objConnection).Fill(dsImport);
            objConnection.Close();

            return dsImport.Tables[0];
        }
```

Access:

```
string sAccessConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Persist Security Info=False;";
using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(sAccessConnection))
{
    con.Open();
    //doing stuffs
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Running Office applications on a server in the context of IIS is fraught with issues. It is even more problematic on x64 bit systems.  There are permission issues, COM issues, DCOM issues, etc. I'd focus on getting Access working, and then try Excel. But I'd see if you can find a solution that doesn't rely on Office.

Comment: If i take my solution to the server, and run it in visual studio in the server, it works. I don't understand what needs to be done in IIS or it's config to get it working.

Comment: It's running under a different user context.  The user running under the IIS application pool is the identity used to access the applications and the file system. You need to give that user the necessary permissions.

Comment: User is Admin that is used in AppPool.

Comment: That's a start.  I'd hit the event log and see what errors are being generated. Also try logging in as that user and running the app in VS. Odds are good you will also have to set up DCOM activations for that user to the office applications.

Comment: I use that user to login in server and when app is run in VS, it works fine. I can't find the office applications list in DCOM. I tried that, too.

Comment: Check this out for the DCOM. http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2012/11/12/microsoft-excel-does-not-appear-in-dcom-configuration-snap-in.aspx

Comment: Great, thanks. Now i can find those office application there. Same solution/code published to three other machine and they all work. But on this machine, it doesn’t work.

Microsoft.Oledb.ACE.12.0 is giving main problem.

To reinstall x64 bit, I followed so many links that pointed how, and I installed according them as well. But it freezes when opening the connection.

I completely uninstalled Office and reinstalled it, too. I exported registry of Office from a machine that works and imported in this one, too. I installed Office Connectivity Tool for Office 2007, too. Nothing helped.